# How to access a value from OnTriggerEnter2D in another function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy, gameobject, ienumerator

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RedHP : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float HP = 5;
    public GameObject BlueWon;
    public GameObject Restart;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trig)
    {
        if (trig.gameObject.tag == "ThrowableBlue")
        {
            StartCoroutine(BowlDestroyTime());
            HP--;
            if (HP <= 0)
            {
                BlueWon.SetActive(true);
                Restart.SetActive(true);
                PlayerBlueController.canMove = false;
                PlayerBlueController.canFire = false;
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator BowlDestroyTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Destroy(trig.gameObject);
    }
}
```

I simply want to destroy my object after too little period of time to make it look better. In `IEnumerator` I can't access `trig.gameObject` because it is defined in `OnTriggerEnter2D`. Is there a way to access this value?
I also tried to put `IEnumerator` in OnTriggerEnter2D it also didn't work. Kinda newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to do that. The [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) function can take a second parameter as a delay time before the Object is destroyed.

```
Destroy(trig.gameObject, 1f);
```

---

If you still want to use coroutine to do this, simply make the `BowlDestroyTime` function to take `GameObject` as parameter then pass the GameObject from the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function to the `BowlDestroyTime` function to be destroyed.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D trig)
{
    if (trig.gameObject.tag == "ThrowableBlue")
    {
        StartCoroutine(BowlDestroyTime(trig.gameObject));
        HP--;
        if (HP <= 0)
        {
            BlueWon.SetActive(true);
            Restart.SetActive(true);
            PlayerBlueController.canMove = false;
            PlayerBlueController.canFire = false;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator BowlDestroyTime(GameObject tartgetObj)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Destroy(tartgetObj);
}
```